# Низкоуровневый звуковой API в Linux

Tags: linux, аудио

Как в Linux возможно низкоуровнево отрендерить звук? (отослать на звуковое устройство частоту звука и воспроизвести её)

Под Windows нашел IAudioRenderClient.

Мне пойдет даже обычный syscall. Главное, чтобы без динамических библиотек можно было это сделать.

Comment: либо какую-нибудь функцию из opengl...

Comment: Там слишком много вариантов в принципе для работы со звуком. Есть GStreamer, libcanberra, ALSA, SDL, Jack, PulseAudio, ... [пруф](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/guide-to-sound-apis.html)

Comment: А почему без динамических либ?

Comment: но в частности тебя практически наверняка будет интересовать `ALSA`... линковаться с `libasound` придётся, но этого бояться бессмысленно т.к. в данном случае она такая же часть API GNU/linux, как и `libc`.

Comment: вопрос, мне за своей прогой не придётся тащить динамическую либу ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я не хочу тащить, так как будет в этом проекте будет ещё кучу либ...
и не хочется за огромной либой тащить ещё одну либу...

Comment: Раз у вас OpenGL, то чем вы открываете окно? Вон, с SDL2 в комплекте идет простенький вывод звука.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я ( с другом ) пытались собрать SDL cmake...
Не вышло, решили с нуля писать...

Comment: А зачем его собирать, если в линуксе он в большинстве пакетных менеджеров идет уже собранный? А под винду и мак сборки можно скачать с https://www.libsdl.org

Comment: `OpenAl`, нет.?

Comment: @VTT Я бы тоже ее посоветовал, но ТС хочет "чтобы без динамических либ". :/